# Содержимое элементов раскидать по input'ам

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть верстка такого плана

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item_l_col">07.08.2018</div>
        <div class="item_line_c_col">Название-1</div>
        <div class="item_line_r_col">Описание-1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item_line_l_col">07.08.2018</div>
        <div class="item_line_c_col">Навазние-2</div>
        <div class="item_line_r_col">Описание-2</div>
    </div>                      
</div>
```

Тут я показал 2 блока `item`. На практике их может быть от нуля до бесконечности (условно).

Необходимо содержимое раскидать это по инпутам, что-то вроде такого:

```
<table class="wrapper" width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <!-- тут сколько угодно всяких строк, не важно -->
    <tr class="row">

        <td width="90%">
            <input type="text" name="group[0][date]" value="07.08.2018" />
            <input type="text" name="group[0][name]" value="Название-1" />
            <input type="text" name="group[0][desc]" Value="Описание-1" />
        </td>

        <td width="10%"><span class="remove">Remove</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">

        <td width="90%">
            <input type="text" name="group[1][date]" value="07.08.2018" />
            <input type="text" name="group[1][name]" value="Название-2" />
            <input type="text" name="group[1][desc]" Value="Описание-2" />
        </td>

        <td width="10%"><span class="remove">Remove</span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Т.е. рассортировать содержимое блоков по соответствующим полям и пронумеровать каждый цикл, начиная с нуля.

За классы цепляться можно. Обертке td у полей тоже можно добавить класс для простоты обращения, если требуется.

Буду признателен js или jq (тут надо использовать each?) вариант исполнения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function () {
var tbody = $('table.wrapper tbody');
$('.wrap .item').each(function(index) {
  var line1 = $(this).find('.item_line_l_col').html();
  var line2 = $(this).find('.item_line_c_col').html();
  var line3 = $(this).find('.item_line_r_col').html();
  
  tbody.append(`<tr class="row">

        <td width="90%">Iteration N ${index}
            <input type="text" name="group[${index}][date]" value="${line1}" />
            <input type="text" name="group[${index}][name]" value="${line2}" />
            <input type="text" name="group[${index}][desc]" Value="${line3}" />
        </td>

        <td width="10%"><span class="remove">Remove</span></td>
    </tr>`)
})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item_line_l_col">07.08.2018</div>
        <div class="item_line_c_col">Название-1</div>
        <div class="item_line_r_col">Описание-1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item_line_l_col">07.08.2018</div>
        <div class="item_line_c_col">Навазние-2</div>
        <div class="item_line_r_col">Описание-2</div>
    </div>
</div>


<table class="wrapper" width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <!-- тут сколько угодно всяких строк, не важно -->
    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Если нужно, то можно вместо шаблона создавать элементы на каждой итерации цикла. Тогда будет удобно навесить обработчики на Remove

Comment: Спасибо за вариант. Кажется одного момента не хватает: не считаются циклы, и не выводится номер в `name="group[]"`

Comment: Счётчик в цикле передаётся параметром https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Добавил в пример кода счётчик

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать.

Comment: Не смог удержаться)) Чтобы совсем всё работало - обработчик `Remove` : `<span class="remove" onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.remove()">Remove</span>`

Comment: @UModeL ) там библиотека для "повторяющихся" полей подключаться будет, это от него кнопку я обозначил.

Answer (score 2):

JS:

```js
(function(){document.querySelectorAll('.wrap .item').forEach(
 function (item, index) {
 var date = item.querySelector('.item_l_col').innerText,
  name = item.querySelector('.item_line_c_col').innerText,
  desc = item.querySelector('.item_line_r_col').innerText,
  tr = document.createElement('tr');
  table = document.querySelector('.wrapper tbody');
 
 tr.innerHTML = `<tr><td width="90%"><input type="text" name="group[${index}][date]" value="${date}" />
 <input type="text" name="group[${index}][name]" value="${name}" />
 <input type="text" name="group[${index}][name]" value="${desc}" />
 </td>
 <td width="10%"><span class="remove">Remove</span><td>
 </tr>`;

 table.append(tr);
})}())
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item_l_col">07.08.2018</div>
        <div class="item_line_c_col">Название-1</div>
        <div class="item_line_r_col">Описание-1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item_l_col">07.08.2018</div>
        <div class="item_line_c_col">Навазние-2</div>
        <div class="item_line_r_col">Описание-2</div>
    </div>                      
</div>


<table class="wrapper" width="100%">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Благодарю за вариант решения. Т.к. "галочка" доступна только одна, отметил ранний вариант на jq, вам +1. Что касается вашей реализации: у `Remove` забыли `td` закрыть. Ну это мелочь. Не смог найти в документации нативного js `append`, вообще, когда код увидел, подумал, что вы в конце использовали jquery функцию для вставки.

Comment: И еще, зачем в конце js кода `()`?

Comment: () - чтобы сразу же и произошел вызов функции.